# Remove text from a file and save, without opening

Tags: sed, files, editors

I am removing duplicated lines of text from a number of files. The command I am trying to use is

```
sed -i 's/set autologout=10//g' /home/$x/.login
```

When I run it, I get this error

```
sed: -I or -i may not be used with stdin
```

The command runs successfully without the `-i` option however it doesn't save it. I am scripting this out as I am modifying 2 files per account on each server. I can code this out with one ugly exception, I can't get it to save.

Comment: I think the -e flag will work in sed. But there is another way to do this without sed (multiple ways). One way im thinking is: `cat file.txt | uniq >> otherfile.txt` may work..

Comment: yes I am on BSD, I will give that a shot\]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What @don_crissti's comment refers, is the fact that [BSD sed seems to *require* an argument for `-i`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sed&sektion=&n=1), and if `-e` isn't used, the first argument is taken as the `sed` command. Which leaves none for the input file, defaulting to `stdin`, and you can't edit that "in-place".

That's as opposed to, say, [GNU sed, which has `-i` take an optional argument](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Command_002dLine-Options).

Or in other words, your `sed` may be interpreting the `s/set autologout=10//g` as a parameter to `-i`, the extension to use for the backup file. So if you don't want to leave a backup file, just give the `-i` option an empty argument:

```
sed -i "" 's/set autologout=10//g' /home/$x/.login
```

Comment: PERFECT !!! sed -i '' -e solved the problem. THANKS !!

Comment: Also -i ""  worked as well !

Answer (score 1):

For POSIX solution, you can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc '%s/set autologout=10//g|x' /home/"$x"/.login
```

1. `%` select all lines
2. `|` command separator
3. `x` write to file if changes have been made (they have) and exit
4. `"$x"` bad to leave variable unquoted in this case